# Organize objective-C string for filters

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I organize this string better for best coding practices. It's a string that defines filters:

```
NSString* string3 = [[[[[[tvA.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"garçon" withString:@"garcon"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Garçon" withString:@"Garcon"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"and"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Is there a way to have it be:

```
NSString* string3 = [[[[[tvA.text filter1] filter2] filter3] filter4] filter5] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be replacing & and + before percent-escaping. The problem is that stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: (IIRC) adds the *minimum* escapes to make it a "valid" URL string, whereas you want to escape anything that might have a special interpretation. For this, use CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes():

```
return [(NSString*)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)aString, NULL, (CFStringRef)@":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=", kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

This encodes & and + correctly, instead of just changing them to "and". It also encodes newlines as %0a (so you might want to replace them with spaces; that's your call), and encodes ç as %C3%A7 (which is decoded correctly if you use UTF-8 on the server).

Comment: hi tc - this works great, but it's crashing the app when any newlines are inputted. How can I make this work?

Comment: I should say, when any 'returns' are inputted. This is inputting to the database perfectly, but when the app tries to load the data, it's crashing.

Comment: How are you "loading" the data? What's the error message? Why are you "filtering" strings before putting them into the database? If it's a database on the phone, just use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd do is capture the transformation into a method somewhere (where "somewhere" is either an instance method on an appropriate object or a class method on a utility class).

```
- (NSString *) transformString: (NSString *) aString
{
    NSString *transformedString;

    transformedString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
    transformedString = [transformedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"];
    transformedString = [transformedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"garçon" withString:@"garcon"];
    transformedString = [transformedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Garçon" withString:@"Garcon"];
    transformedString = [transformedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"and"];
    transformedString = [transformedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    return transformedString;
}
```

Then:

```
NSString *result = [myTransformer transformString: tVA.text];
```

A bit brutish, but it'll work.   And by "brutish", I mean that it is going to be slow and will cause a bunch of interim strings to pile up in the autorelease pool.   However, if this is something that you only do every now and then, don't worry about it -- while brutish, it is certainly quite straightforward.

If, however, this shows up in performance analysis as a bottleneck, you could first move to using `NSMutableString` as it has methods for doing replacements in place.   That, at least, will reduce memory thrash and will likely be a bit faster in that there is less copying of strings going on.

If *that* is still too slow, then you will likely need to write yourself a fun little bit of parsing and processing code that walks through the original and copies it to new a new string while also doing any necessary transforms along the way.

But, don't bother optimizing until you prove that it is a problem.  And, of course, if it is a problem, you have just one method to optimize!

Comment: And if ever you *do* find yourself wanting/needing to transform the contents of a string on the fly, you might want to take a look at NSScanner: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000147-BCIEFGHC

Comment: You can mitigate problems with objects piling up in the autorelease pool by creating a new pool at the beginning of the method and draining it before returning.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not crucial, put the strings and their replacements into an `NSDictionary` and iterate over the items. Put it all in a helper method and use a `NSMutableString` to work on it (which reduces at least *some* of the cost).